# How to write client to server app for Ubuntu?

Tags: server, windows, client

I have a question, when I was working on windows, I write Client to Server Chat program by tutorial, but the I add many functions that was very usable. I am going to write user friendly app for Linux and use client to server chat program which will work, from linux to linux, linux to windows.
When I make an app I upload a video on youtube. [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyMXydY9FFg) to view it.
I know programming in Visual Basic, and my question is: Can anybody show me the right way to make the program(Just tutorial or something like that)?

Comment: There is no *right* way, given that you can program in C, C++, Python Java, Perl, Haskell, ... Pick a language, first. If you want something friendly, try Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several languages available to write programs in under Linux. Mono *may* be a good start for you as you are more familiar with the windows world.

GTK (using c++ or python) seem to be very popular these days. There is always java. QT is pretty good and it works in most anything, C++ being what I see the most.

All in all you need to start by picking a language, and there are many to choose from. There is no "best" language, but, if you don't use Java or Mono, then your going to want to choose a widget set that works cross platform. QT and GTK work on most everything.

So pick a widget set by looking at QT and GTK and seeing which style looks better to you to code in (again tons of differences here, QT is more of a stack and GTK is more "just widgets" for example).

Next pick a language that integrates well with the widgets you chose. Make sure to keep in mind cross platform compatibility.

Finally, I would suggest you start re-writing your windows version first. So your only learning a new language and stack and not having to relearn core OS stuff.  Then you can port that code over to Linux. If you kept an eye on cross platfom compatibility, it should not be too much of a big deal.

When finished you will have a code base, that can be compiled or whatever to give you an application that will run on Linux, Mac, Windows, mobile phones, toaster ovens, and car speedometers.

Also don't be afraid to look at current open source projects, and leverage them. Could your chat program exist as a plugin in pidgen? (for example) If it could your project just got easier and your product better.